# Wrong screen resolution Windows 7/8

Tags: windows, graphics-card, display, resolution

I know this has been asked many times before, but I have not yet found a solution...

So as the title says, my computer displays the wrong screen resolution. What happened, was the power went down one day shutting down my computer, but I waited till the next day to boot it up again. When I did, my resolution was at 1600x1200. At the time I was trying Windows 8, so I tried reinstalling my ATI's drivers (cleanly of course), changing what type of monitor Windows displayed, installing drivers for my monitor, although it had worked perfectly up to that point, formatting my computer and reverting back to Windows 7, yet nothing worked.

If I try setting 1920x1080 (which is my desired resolution) via Windows, it reverts to 1920x1080 at 30Hz interlaced. If I go through CCC, I can change to the correct resolution and refresh rate, but windows won't remember it next time. Minor inconvenience, I know, but annoying nonetheless.

So, now I am using the Generic non-PnP Monitor from Windows with a set resolution from CCC.

My specs are:

> OS: Windows 7 x64
>   Monitor: LG Flatron W2243S
>   Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 5870
>   Motherboard: MSI 890GXM-G65 (MS-7642)

***Edit:*** I had been using 1920x1080 for quite a few years with this monitor and graphics card, so the resolution is compatible.
***Edit 2:*** I just noticed that CCC shows my monitor as an analog CRT. Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: you mean 1920*1080 but that is a minor detail i guess

Comment: Have you tried using a restore point?  Please make sure all your information is 100% correct it seems like you have minor problems with the details.

Comment: @TheUser1024 True that, I always confuse them!

Comment: @Ramhound As I said in the description, I did a clean format from windows 8 to windows 7. So a system restore/program is not the culprit.

Comment: @Charlie - If your monitor is not being detected correctly that woudl have everything to do with it.  Have you replaced all cables?

Comment: @Ramhound I am going to buy an HDMI cable to check it out. I should be done in something like an hour, so I'll get back to you then. --Scratch the HDMI part, going for a plain cable ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, I figured it out. It seems that indeed, it was the VGA cable. It must have got fried or something.

The steps I took where:

> 1. Change cable.
> 2. Uninstall graphic card drivers.
> 3. Reboot and reinstall graphic card drivers.
> 4. Voila! Ready!

So, for anyone else having a similar problem, change your cable or adapter!